# how to close network stream connection properly?

Tags: c#, networking

I have an application that is connecting to some network server (tcp) and is connected using a network stream:

```
if (!SSL)
{
     _networkStream = new System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient(Server, Port).GetStream();
     _StreamWriter = new System.IO.StreamWriter(_networkStream);
     _StreamReader = new System.IO.StreamReader(_networkStream, Encoding.UTF8);
}

if (SSL)
{
     System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient client = new System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient(Server, Port);
     _networkSsl = new System.Net.Security.SslStream(client.GetStream(), false,
                    new System.Net.Security.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(Protocol.ValidateServerCertificate), null);
     _networkSsl.AuthenticateAsClient(Server);
     _StreamWriter = new System.IO.StreamWriter(_networkSsl);
     _StreamReader = new System.IO.StreamReader(_networkSsl, Encoding.UTF8);
}

///// since now I working with both reader and writer globally in multiple threads
```

I am using reader and writer asynchronously (in 2 threads) and I need to have both of these streams globally available (they are defined as public references on class level), so I don't know if `using` statement can be used here.

How should I properly close this connection? All objects (`NetworkStream`, stream writer and reader) have the Close() method. Should I call it for all of them? Or only 1 of them? Is there any need to release some resources?

Answer (score 2):

Put them in a `using` block.  It will close and dispose of each stream appropriately after the operation has been completed.

```
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(_networkStream, Encoding.UTF8)) 
{

}
```

Comment: Would this end the connection after this block of code, or it would only release the reader?

Comment: @Petr - you can nest them, the connection will only be closed after the reader and writer have been disposed of and the network stream has no data to be read.

Comment: you say "only if the network stream had no data to be read" but what if server is sending some data to network stream (it has data to read) but I want to forcefully close the connection anyway?

Comment: @Petr then you can explicitly close the connection by using `.Close()` - however this will probably result in you using data if you force the stream to be closed while it is reading.

Answer (score 0):

Use using() {} blocks. This way all Connections/streams are properly closed after usage.

```
using(_networkStream = new System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient(Server, Port).GetStream())
{
    using(_StreamWriter = new System.IO.StreamWriter(_networkStream))
    {
      //do stuff
    }
    using(_StreamReader = new System.IO.StreamReader(_networkStream, Encoding.UTF8))
    {
       //do stuff
    } 
 }
```

Comment: what if I want to read and write using this stream asynchronously? should I nest the reader into writer? (The reader is running in different thread than writer)

Answer (score 0):

When they are disposed of, `StreamReader` and `StreamWriter` each dispose of the underlying `NetworkStream` automatically by default.  Because of this, if you are using both a reader and a writer, you might get an "object already disposed" type of exception when you try to close the second one.  I prefer to dispose of the stream itself but not the reader/writer since it's pointless in that case.

```
using stream = tcpClient.GetStream();
var reader = new StreamReader(stream);
var writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
// <use reader and writer>
// <the using statement ensures the stream is disposed of>
```

If you insist on disposing of the reader and writer, you can disable their default auto-close-the-stream behavior via the `leaveOpen` parameter:

```
new StreamReader(stream, leaveOpen: true)
new StreamWriter(stream, leaveOpen: true)
```

Making use of `using` is ideal if possible, but the other way to accomplish the same is to manually call the stream's `Close()` method or, equivalently, its `Dispose()` method.